# How to get html input values like Laravel using Interfaces

Tags: php, class, input, interface

I would like to get HTML data using an interfaced method like a Request. If anyone knows please explain me.

I would like to get output like this one! please help to write a sample Request php interface.

My real scenario is I have a controller that controller has a function Create. create function passed a parameter as a Request class. I want access to HTML input as I mentioned in the question. That is my problem.

```
<input name="inputname">
<input name="anotherinputname">
```

```
public function create(Request $request) {
   echo $request->inputname;
   echo $request->anotherinputname;
}
```

So please help to make Request class. Thanks

Comment: You don't "get" anything from interfaces. An interface is just a contract that a class has to follow when it implements that interface. Are you asking how to build a request class? That's too broad of a question. Do the [appropriate amount of research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and make some attempts yourself first. If you get stuck on something specific along the way, post a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and explain where you're stuck.

Comment: What do you mean by "interfaced method"? How is this related to a "request"?

Comment: suppose you can please check this URL https://github.com/Katheesh/Mailer-API-Laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/MailController.php.  How to implement Request class like Laravel controller. thanks for your time!

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: @M.Eriksson I have already researched it. but I can’t find a solution to my requirement.  I clearly mentioned my problem in a question. but you did not understand my question.  I don't like to type too much. 

My real scenario is I have a controller that controller has a function Create. create function passed a parameter as a Request class. I want access to HTML input as I mentioned in the question. That is my problem. so if you can please help to make Request class.

Comment: **Please add all clarification to your question by editing it** - you haven't explained what is missing to fulfill your requirements

Comment: _"I clearly mentioned my problem in a question"_ - No you didn't. Now you've added what you actually want, but it's still unclear where _exactly_ you're stuck. Creating a class? Getting the submitted data from a POST and/or GET request? Fetching the data as class properties? Injecting the class into a method? Making the class implement an interface? Creating an interface? We're glad to help you with specific issues you might run into, but we're not here to write your code for you (which a proper answer here would require us to).

Answer (score 1):

It's not working as you think.
Laravel uses dependency injection.
You can define a Request class and in its constructor, you can map the POST data to properties.
something like this:

```
class Request {
    public $get;
    public $post;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->get = $_GET;
        $this->post = $_POST;
    }
}
```

and then you can access the POST data this way:

```
$request->post['anotherinputname'];
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you have this method in your controller:

```
public function create(Request $request) {
```

You should grab your variables by doing:

```
$field = $request->get('fieldName');
dump($field);
```